# Get a specific object from url ( API ) and print the value in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

Please i want to get a value from API with JSON , but the object wanted is duplicated and i don't know how to chose the value of this object

[image: This is a screen of the API]

in the screen I have an object named "region" but it's duplicated many times, so i want to get just the first value

[image: the wanted value]

and this is my code javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    cas confirmé<p id="1"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    cas recovered<p id="2"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    cas decedés<p id="3"></p>
</body>

<script>

    const api = 'https://covidma.herokuapp.com/api?fbclid=IwAR2Zsptom8RZPknstJrmlJwaCKfSTvxyO5fOCAUt_NNN9YvbsSPq1b_kF0o';

    async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch(api);
        const data = await response.json();
        const [{ confirmed , recovered , region }] = data;

        document.getElementById('1').textContent = confirmed;
        document.getElementById('2').textContent = recovered;
        document.getElementById('3').textContent = region[0];
    }
    getData();



</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Post code, not a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment has noted, it's always easiest to post code instead of a screenshot.

From what I could tell, the correct index should be:

```js
const { confirmed, recovered, region } = data[0][0]
```

If above doesn't work, please update your question with actual code, instead of screenshots.

You can use markdown codeblocks: ```code```